# Listener for before all activities start and after all activities stop?

Tags: java, android

If I want to run some scripts before any activity starts and after all activity stops, Where would I put such a  listener in android?

Ive considered putting it in the Android `Application` class, and simply put the methods inside its `onCreate` and `onSaveInstanceState` - but I am not sure they get called before and after all activites

Comment: It's best to describe *why* you want this behavior, to ensure you aren't falling victim to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - maybe there's an easier, more efficient way to achieve the behavior you desire.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I am manipulating multiple models `User`, `Comment`, `Post` - all of which contain simple auto increment Long IDs and some primitive attributes (e.g. int age, String text).

Since I have multiple activites accessing them - a view profile activity, and a modify profile activity - I wanted to create an overarching class to load all required models to some static class or a modified `Application` class. During runtime all activites would just manipulate these objects from that class - keeping everyone in sync and avoiding costly IO. Then when the activities all shut down, it saves

Comment: For load you can implement `load on demand` and for save `avoiding costly IO` sounds like premature optimisation since android cannot garantee that onPause/ onDestroy method is always called and would lead to data loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately in the Application class there is no callback when the application has stopped, but I think you can try this code:

<< here was old code >>

**Updated**:
Code of Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startService(new Intent(this, Monitor.class));
    }
}
```

The code of background service:

```
public class Monitor extends Service implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "Monitor";

    int mActivitiesCount = 1; // At the moment when service started, the main Activity is already opened

    public Monitor() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getApplication().unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
        mActivitiesCount++;
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: count: " + mActivitiesCount);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        mActivitiesCount--;
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityDestroyed: count: " + mActivitiesCount);
        if (mActivitiesCount == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "All activities was destroyed");
            // do something
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it, this does not work because HashSet resets during `onCreate` - because again, we are back at square one. Your solution works if Application lives past all the activities, and doesn't die before them

Comment: @Alan, you can start empty "STICKY" background service in 'onCreate()' method of Application and stop it when all activities destroyed. This will allow the application staying alive even if there is no any running Activity.

Comment: could you provide an example/pseudocode/or some links on how one would do such a thing so I can accept your response as the answer?

Comment: @Alan, please try updated code. Let me know if it does not work too.